# Exit application with Application.Exit without showing GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, exit

Summary:
When the application is not run with a specified user account the application exits but still creates a GUI. I want it to completely exit

Details:
I would have thought that the code I have below would work. It checks for a specific attribute of the username, if it doesn't have it, the app closes. Simple. The problem is that the application still creates a GUI even if the user name doesn't contain that attribute. Any ideas?

This code is in my main method. It is a windows form.

Code:

```
public ProgramMain()
{
    String runningUser = Environment.UserName;
    if (!runningUser.Contains("asdf"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must run this application with your asdf account.");
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code inside your `Main` method?  Also, is this WPF, Winforms, or something else?

Comment: this code is in my main method. it is a windows form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Program.cs file in Main you will see Application.Run() If you do the check before this line of code is hit. Then if the user is not correct, just skip the line.

Application.Run() is line to start the application run loop.

If the Run Loop is never hit and main is exited. the application will exit.

Comment: +1. This is how I handle duplicate instances of my application being run.

Comment: Thanks Jason. That makes sense. I just fixed my code. Ill make you as my solution.

Answer (score 5):

You are coding in the form and not in the Main() event in program.cs. If you exit before the form is actually instantiated, you will not get a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You are too far. InitializeComponent looks like you are already inside a Windows Form. Then you have already created a Window. Put your check in the main method before the form is created then nothing is displayed.
You can break in the debugger and check the call stack. Search for the first method where the code is from your project. Put in this method the check and you should be fine.

Yours,
  Alois Kraus

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are doing it in the constructor call of your control.Try doing this checking in the Main method of Program class.